# How to replace bullets from swiper-pagination-bullets (swiper js) by images ? The same images as from the swiper

Tags: pagination, swiper.js

I am using a swiper from swiper JS on my product page to show images of the product, and I would like the pagination to be miniatures of the images instead of being bullets as it is currently.

my HTML is just  appearing under my 
And my js is :

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper--product', {
loop: true,
spaceBetween: 15,

```
el: '.swiper-pagination',
```

},

navigation: {
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
}
});

Could you please help me to find out how to add images in the pagination please ? I am open on different ways to do it

thanks for your help,

Jaal

I did not try anything yet.